# How to get the difference between minimum and maximum stock for each product?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to get maximum and minimum stock for each product and calculate the difference between these values. If a stock is equal to `null` or is empty, then it should be substituted by 0.

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("product_pk")
val sales = df
             .select($"product_pk",$"stock")
             .withColumn("sold",max($"stock")-min($"stock").over(windowSpec))
```

But I get this error when I run my code. I do not understand why I cannot use `Window` with `product_pk`:

> diagnostics: User class threw exception:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence
>   is empty, and 'mytable.`product_pk`' is not an aggregate function.
>   Wrap '(max(mytable.`stock`) AS `_w0`)' in windowing function(s) or
>   wrap 'mytable.`product_pk`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't
>   care which value you get.;;

Or should I use `groupBy` product_pk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently you use `max` in the wrong context (no window specified), try:

```
val sales = df
  .select($"product_pk",$"stock")
  .withColumn("sold",max($"stock").over(windowSpec)-min($"stock").over(windowSpec))
```

You can also use groupBy :

```
val sales = df
  .groupBy($"product_pk",$"stock")
    .agg(
      max($"stock").as("max_stock"),
      min($"stock").as("min_stock")
    )
  .withColumn("sold",coalesce($"max_stock"-$"min_stock",lit(0.0)))
```

Comment: But now `sales` has a lot of duplicates. it looks like the same values of `product_pk`, `stock` and `sold` are duplicated many times.

Comment: Also, how can I handle empty or null values of stock? I want them to be substituted by 0.

Comment: of course, window-function gives you 1 record for each record in your source-dataframe. If you don't want that, use groupBy. you can replace null with 0 using the coalsece-function

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I should do: `.groupBy($"product_pk").withColumn("sold",max($"stock").over(windowSpec)-min($"stock").over(windowSpec))`

Comment: Or do you mean: `.groupBy($"product_pk")..withColumn("sold",max($"stock")-min($"s‌​tock"))`? The values of max and min should refer to the same product_pk.